# philosophical quotation

Tags: epistemology, reference-request, ontology

Who said the following?
"what is isn't and what isn't is"

I can't remember where I picked up that line but I seem to remember hearing it being repeated by some fictional character, possibly cartoonish.

Comment: See Gorgias, "[On Nature](http://academic.mu.edu/taylorr/Ancient_Philosophy_Spring_2016/Gorgias_On_Nature.html)".

Answer (score 1):

To quote Aristotle “Affirming nonexistence of the extent, or existence of the nonexistent, is falsehood; but affirming existence of the existent, and nonexistence of the nonexistent, is truth.”